# Memory leaked and crash app using gif in uiscrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, uiscrollview, gif

When I use three GIFs in a UIScrollview the app leaks more memory and crashed at a point. I use SDWebImage for loading GIFs.

My code:

```
- (void)setupScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrMain {
      for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        UIImageView *imgV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i)*scrMain.frame.size.width + self.view.frame.size.width/2 - (IS_IPHONE_5 ? 215 : (iPhone6 ? 250 : iPhone6Plus ? 360 : 215))/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2 - 355/2, (IS_IPHONE_5 ? 215 : (iPhone6 ? 250 : iPhone6Plus ? 360 : 215)), 355)];
        // set scale to fill
        imgV.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        // set image
        [imgV setImage:[UIImage sd_animatedGIFNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"help%d",i+1]]];
        imgV.tag=i+1;
        //   add to scrollView
        [scrMain addSubview:imgV];
      }
      // set the content size to 4 image width
      [scrMain setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrMain.frame.size.width*3, scrMain.frame.size.height)];

}
```

How to load GIFs without memory leaks?

All solutions are appreciated!!

Comment: Try this https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif

Comment: Same result for this too. App crash due to high memory